# docker problem with create database becouse of LoadError: libpcap.so.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ubuntu, libpcap

Hi I have got a problem with creating database in docker.

I tried to create a database with:

```
docker-compose run snort_web_interface bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

and I have got an error.

> LoadError: libpcap.so.0.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or  directory - /box/gems/pcaprub-0.13.0/lib/pcaprub_c.so

docker-compose up is running.

I install packages, gems etc with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get -qq -y install libpq-dev
apt-get -qq -y install nodejs
apt-get -qq -y install libpcap-dev


bundle check || bundle install

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
    rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

**Any idea how to fix it?? Docker is running good, only one problem is with libpcap library.**

Comment: If you want dockerfile or docker-compose.yml I post it, but I think that there is no problem

Comment: check of the below answers your question or share any  your experience if the issue has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the required libraries is missing a dependency or juts a required file.

In your case, this file can not be found: `pcaprub_c.so` 
 I have seen this issue numerous times, in a Redhat distro, and was able to solve in two steps:

1) Find the name of the package that is missing the file. In Redhat/Cntos, you run this command:

```
 sudo yum whatprovides '*filename'
```

For Debian based Distros, a quick google search suggested:

`dpkg -S  filename` ( in your case it's pcaprub_c.so)

Once you know the name of the package,that is causing the issue, you just remove and reinstall or just install:

```
sudo apt-get install blah-blah-package.
```

For redhat/centos..etc:

```
 sudo yum install blah-blah-package.
```